# Saving a range of Cells in Excel as HTML using Win32::OLE Perl module

Tags: perl, winapi, excel, automation, ole

I want to save a range of cells in XLS sheet as a HTML file, using a Perl script. I have googled for solutions to this problem. But haven't found any.

However there is a solution similar to this using Excel VBA:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, _
"C:\Documents and Settings\Tim\Desktop\Page.htm", _
Selection.Parent.Name, _
Selection.Address(), _
xlHtmlStatic, "divExcelExport", _
"TestTitle")
.Publish (True)
.AutoRepublish = False
End With
```

So, I tried converting this to Perl code, but it gives me the following errors:

H:\test_code\data>perl a.pl
Win32::OLE(0.1702) error 0x800a03ec
    in METHOD/PROPERTYGET "Add"
H:\test_code\data>

```
use strict;
use warnings "all";
use Win32::OLE;
my $Excel = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application') || 
            Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application','Quit');
my $Book = $Excel->Workbooks->Open("H:\\test_code\\data\\test.xls");
my $Sheet = $Book->Worksheets(1);
$Book->PublishObjects->Add({SourceType=>5, # int value for xlSourceRange
                            FileName => "H:\\test_code\\data\\test2.html",
                            Source => $Sheet->Range("A1:B2")->Address,
                            HtmlType => 0, # xlHtmlStatic s int value.
                           });
print Win32::OLE->LastError();
$Book->Close(0);
exit();
```

Can some one please suggest a solution for this problem.

Note, that I want to preserve all the formatting of the columns, (Decimal, number of digits, $ Sign, color etc..). Any solution which doesn't involve usage of  a commercial library is appreciated.

Thanks,
Rizwan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, at least the HTML file is being generated:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';

my $Excel = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application','Quit');
my $Book  = $Excel->Workbooks->Open("C:\\test.xls");
$Book->PublishObjects->Add(xlSourceRange,
    "C:\\output_file.htm", 'Sheet1', '$C$3:$C$10', xlHtmlStatic
)->Publish(1);
$Book->Close(0);
$Excel->Quit;
```

Comment: Thanks bvr this seems to work. The catch is to use Win32::OLE::Const, and directly use the constant instead of its integer value.